# Get the first non-matching criteria from a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
   |       A              B           
---|----------------------------------------- 
1  |     Test 1          O.K.       
2  |     Test 2          O.K.
3  |     Test 3          General Error
4  |     Test 4          O.K.
5  |     Test 5          Detail Error
6  |     Test 6          O.K.
---|----------------------------------------- 
7  |                     General Error
8  |
```

---

In the table I have a list of different tests (`Column A`) and their results (`Column B`). 
Now, I am looking for a formula in `Cell B7` which always displays the **first error** it can find within `Range("B1:B6")`. 
 Basically, something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP( --> non-o.k. <-- ,B1:B6,1,FALSE)
```

Is there a `VLOOKUP` function that looks for the **first non-matching criteria**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
=LOOKUP(1,1/(B1:B6<>"O.K."),B1:B6)
```

Or rather:

```
=@FILTER(B1:B6,B1:B6<>"O.K.","")
```